# Nullpointer on getIntent().getExtras();

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, qtandroidextras

code in RegisterActivity1:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();

...

case R.id.continue_button:

extras.putString("email",eMail_eingabe.getText().toString().trim());
extras.putString("pw1", passwort_1_eingabe.getText().toString().trim());
extras.putString("pw2", passwort_2_eingabe.getText().toString().trim());
i.putExtras(extras);
this.startActivity(i);

break;
```

code in RegisterActivity2:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //Nullpointer oocurs here

semail = extras.getString("email");
spw1 = extras.getString("pw1");
spw2 = extras.getString("pw2");
```

I'm trying to pass email and password from activity 1 to activity 2, but nothing I have tried so far seems to be working. I always get a Nullpointer Exception here:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Any tips on how to fix this?

Here is the full method from Activity1, in case it has something to do with the override method...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    String email = eMail_eingabe.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwort_1_eingabe.getText().toString().trim();


    if (eMail_eingabe.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        //eMail_eingabe.setError("Bitte email eingeben");
        eMail_eingabe.setText("Bitte email eingeben");
        eMail_eingabe.requestFocus();
        return;
    }


    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        eMail_eingabe.setError("Bitte eine gültige E-Mail eingeben");
        eMail_eingabe.requestFocus();
        return;
    }


    if (password.length() < 6) {
        passwort_1_eingabe.setError("Bitte mindestens 6 Zeichen eingeben");
        passwort_1_eingabe.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (passwort_1_eingabe.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        passwort_1_eingabe.setError("Bitte passwort eingeben");
        passwort_1_eingabe.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (passwort_2_eingabe.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        passwort_2_eingabe.setError("Bitte passwort eingeben");
        passwort_2_eingabe.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!passwort_1_eingabe.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(passwort_2_eingabe.getText().toString())) {
        passwort_2_eingabe.setError("Passwort stimmt nicht überein");
        passwort_2_eingabe.requestFocus();
        return;
    }


    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.continue_button:

            extras.putString("email", eMail_eingabe.getText().toString().trim());
            extras.putString("pw1", passwort_1_eingabe.getText().toString().trim());
            extras.putString("pw2", passwort_2_eingabe.getText().toString().trim());
            i.putExtras(extras);
            this.startActivity(i);

            break;


    }
}
```

Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hoimi, PID: 7812
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hoimi/com.example.hoimi.student.Register2_Student_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3355)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.hoimi.student.Register2_Student_Activity.<init>(Register2_Student_Activity.java:22)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3340)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace

Comment: Where you initialize the intent?

Comment: Where is intent reference (i) ?  How declared i ?

Comment: Intent i; above the onCreate method and  i = new Intent(this, Register2_Student_Activity.class); inside of the onCreate method

Comment: Where are you trying to use `getIntent()`. Error says this is null. In `onCreate` it should not be null

Comment: Put complete section of  your Register2_Student_Activity where you do get intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call `getIntent()`, it returns the intent that you created in previous Activity.

> public Intent getIntent ()
>
> Return the intent that started this activity.

[Activity documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent())

so in second activity, your intent is `null`

in `onCreate` initiate your intent

Comment: That's a good point. I wonder why it's got down voted 2 times.

Answer (score 3):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

had to be called in the onCreate method, I called it before so it didn't work.

Someone gave the right answer, but deleted his post later (because he got 2 downvotes??)

Anyways, thanks alot.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not because of `getExtras()` its because of `getIntent()`. Check your getIntent() with null and use further.

Your code should be something like

```
if(getIntent() != null) {
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //Nullpointer oocurs here
semail = extras.getString("email");
spw1 = extras.getString("pw1");
spw2 = extras.getString("pw2");
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Just a quick note, in some situations, checking specifically for `getIntent().getExtras() != null` seems to help when otherwise just checking for `getIntent() != null` leads to a _NullPointer Exception_